# JSon deserialize for hash

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

In my senario, there is a piece of code like below in the JSon response entity:

```
"hashkeys":
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3"
}
```

The keys like "key1","key2","key3", (and even the number of the keys), are only known at runtime, but cannot be determined at coding time.

How can I code the JSon entity to deserialize such kind of response? I am using C# language DataContractJsonSerializer.

My testing code:

```
[DataContract]
class Test {
    [DataMember(Name = "hashkeys")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> dic { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    public static T FromJson<T>(string strJson) where T : class
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJson)))
        {
            return ds.ReadObject(ms) as T;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{""hashkeys"":{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}}";
        Test MyResponse = FromJson<Test>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(MyResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: your testing code seems work if you change json string like this `@"{""hashkeys"":{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}}"`

Comment: You are right. But after deserialization, the dictionary, which is what I need, has no values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

Make a `Dictionary` of `string` and `string` like this

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";   
Dictonary<string,string> MyResponse =     JsonConvert.DesirializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(values.Count);
// 2
Console.WriteLine(values["key1"]);
// Value1
```

For more examples and references [Click Here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm)

Comment: Thanks for response, Kaushik and Marcin. The type Dictionary<string, string> is good for me. But I am using DataContractJsonSerializer, instead of newtonking json serialize lib.

Comment: newtonking is providing lot of feature in `json` so I personally prefer that. I'll recommend you should also use that. that will help you to do the task easily.

Comment: @WeiquanZhang Deserialization to `Dictionary<string, string>` should work just fine with `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: I found the difference. If I use DataContractJsonSerializer, it need to tag "Key" and "Value" in the response, that is, the response should look like {"Key":"key1"","Value":"value1"},{"Key":"key2"","Value":"value2"}". Newtonking implement is more straightforward. Since I cannot touch service side code, newtonking is the only choice for me...

Comment: @WeiquanZhang Hmmmmmmm, That's sounds great ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize it to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

It's a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, which is exactly what you're trying to deal with. `"KeyX"` will become `Key` and `"valueX"` will be the `Value` for dictionary entiry.